# Laravel8 laravelcollective/remote can I create a dynamic connection

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, remote-server

I'm migrating our inhouse backup app onto Laravel8, so far so good. I'm interested in using the laravelcollective/remote facade (SSH) to ssh onto the remote server and run some commands which it looks like this would be very good at (rather than using php exec() methods the current backup app uses).

My question however is, can i build an array/object from the database and use these details as a connection without having to manually maintain the config/remote.php file? Maintaining this with any server changes will be a nightmare to maintain as we frequently update users and sites are added removed on a regular basis! any ideas? As mentioned we are storing the ssh creds in the database which is populated via a connection form within the app.

I've built a simple test function in a controller and stepped into this with my debugger. I expected to see the array/object which is created from the config/remote file and was planning to just add new items but i couldn't find any array/objects containing the default empty production config set as default in the config/remote.php file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SSH;

class SecureServerController extends Controller
{
    public function test() {
        SSH::into()->run([
            'cd /var/www',
            'git pull origin master'
        ], function($line)
        {
            echo $line.PHP_EOL;
        });
    }
}
```

The following is the route used:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SecureServerController;
Route::get('/test', [SecureServerController::class, 'test']);
```

thanks

*** EDIT ***
SO I had a look at the code for the SSH facade and found I could create a config file and pass this via the connect function:

```
        $config = [
            'host' => '123.123.123.123',
            'username' => 'the-user',
            'password' => 'a-password'
        ];

        SSH::connect($config)->run([
            'cd /var/www',
            'git pull origin master'
        ], function($line)
        {
            echo $line.PHP_EOL;
        });
```

However i see no way to use any port except 22. almost all our servers use a non default port as an additional level of obfuscation.

Comment: The default config is pulled [in `RemoteManager`](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote/blob/f4b200f24f76307b09d7a5af230ea7119cbf9811/src/RemoteManager.php#L155-L183). You might be able to do it via runtime config setting, e.g. `config()->set('key', 'value')`. Personally I'd just extend `RemoteManager` and add/overwrite the methods needed to pass in configs at runtime.

Comment: Yeah looks like that would be the way to do this (see my recent edit where I just create a config object and pass to the connect function). I've since noticed that this facade doesn't seem to allow a port that isn't 22 which probably means using another solution for connecting

Comment: Put it on your host. `123.123.123.123:9876`